# PHP recursion stuck

Tags: php, recursion

I am trying to recurse through a multidimensional Object/Array structure to create JSON, but the following isn't working. $data is reset, but I'm not sure how to prevent this.

```php
public function encodeJSON($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
            $json->$key = $this->encodeJSON($value);
        } else {
            $json->$key = $value;
        }
    }
    return json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: While your thought process is a little off so this doesn't actually create valid JSON, it does recurse, and `$data` is not reset. It produces one string with all of the values including nested arrays. I tested it on several arrays.

Comment: As a side note: encoding values individually will produce incorrect JSON! You'll end up with something like `{"foo":"{\"bar\":\"baz\"}"}` instead of the intended `{"foo":{"bar":"baz"}}`. You need to encode the whole object/array at once.

Comment: @Dan - Exactly.  I'm not really sure what mike628 is trying to do here.  Mike - what's wrong with the return value of `json_encode($data);`?  json_encode() is perfectly capable of serializing arrays and objects!

Comment: I am trying to json_encode an object structure that includes private members. So, I am trying to take it out of the object and encode it. My test data is this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878141/json-encode-missing-data

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to learn recursion that's one thing, but at least for me json_encode automatically encodes objects and arrays recursively so it's not really necessary to write the extra function.

Tested with this code:

```
class TestClass {
    var $c1;
    var $c2;

    function __construct() {
        $this->c1 = 'member variable 1';
        $this->c2 = 8080;
    }
}

$test = array('hello' => 'world', 'age' => 30,
    'arr' => array('a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd'), 'obj' => new TestClass());

echo(json_encode($test));
// I get the following JSON object:
// {"hello":"world","age":30,"arr":{"a":"b","c":"d"},"obj":{"c1":"member variable 1","c2":8080}}
```